# Custom colors of panel background: datapoints are masked

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, background

I would like to have a plot with a custom panel background, with three differently coloured area as background (let's say, yellow, gold and no color).

I can manage to set the panel bakground in the way I would like, using **geom_rect()** in ggplot.

But... background colours are not really in the background. Indeed, colors are in front of my datapoints. This makes the plot a bit weird and difficult to read.
I also tried to use **alpha=0.2** to set transparency, but this does not solve the problem.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=seq(1,5,1),
                      trait=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=5),
                      mm=c(0.123, 0.89416, 0.4541, 0.233, 0.7794, 0.32554, 0.5554, 0.64122, 0.115, 0.5441, 0.3332, 0.1452, 0.5413, 0.418, 0.1852))
```

And this is the plot:

```
  geom_point(shape=21) + 
  scale_size_area(max_size=10, guide=guide_legend(title.position="top", nrow=4, title="%"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name=NULL,values=c("lightskyblue","limegreen","purple"))+
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=0,xmax=1.5,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf), fill="yellow", alpha=0.05)+
  geom_rect(data=NULL,aes(xmin=1.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf), fill="gold", alpha=0.05)
```

[wrong plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbH3r.jpg)
[image]

How can I force geom_rect to really be in the back and my datapoints in the front?

Comment: Change the order of the layers. `ggplot() + geom_rect() + geom_point()`

Comment: Have you considered calling `geom_point()` after your `geom_rect()`s?

Comment: A-ah! Now it works =) and it was so simple... thank you guys!